# Has anyone updated 20.04 with new kernel 5.4.0-39 yesterday resulting in nvidia driver problems?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 20.04

Yesterday I upgraded my kernel from  5.4.0-37 to 5.4.0.39. Upon reboot lost the second monitor, mouse jerky, display sluggish. Downgraded to 5.4.0-37 and all issues resolved. The NVidia driver is 440. The graphics adapter is GeForce 1050 Ti. Updated my other machine with intel graphics with no issue.

Comment: Did you made a search in your logs? Type `journalctl --list-boots` and choose one where you know the kernel x.39 was loaded; that is note the first  number of its row (something like -b12). Now search the log for errors `journalctl -b <put here your boot, eg. -b12> -p3 ` and report about it.

Comment: No I did not. I knew the kernel was the issue. It loaded because I checked. Rebooted into grub advanced menu and loaded the previous kernel. All back to normal. Altered grub to include GRUB_DEFAULT=saved and GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true. Then I could used the pc for the next 24 hours. Next day 22 updates for nvidia driver. Then changed back to the new kernel.

Comment: How did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: The update required for 440 drivers was obtained using "apt update". They were available the day after kernel 5.4.0-39 was upgraded. Assuming you already had the original 440 driver install. Otherwise they are installed via "Software & Updates" additional drivers tab.

Comment: Check that the `dkms` modules are rebuilt and installed for your new kernel: `dkms status`
This should output lines with installed `dkms` kernel modules like: `nvidia-340, 340.108, 5.4.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same Graphics. Already resolved in update few hours later for me. There's no need to downgrade Kernel. You should also check for updates in ***Software center & Software updater**.* I had to update my Snapd application manually, to be fully complete.

Then just type into Terminal :

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt autoremove

reboot
```

Comment: Yes, got up this morning and noticed like 22 updates relative to the kernel upgrade and nvidia. It fixed the issue they created in the first place. I've got grub set up to run and stay running on the kernel I chose using the grub menu at boot. That got me thru the day until this morning. The last kernel is not compatible with these new changes either. 

Same thing happened on manjaro except it never made it to the desktop. Some sort of display error. I'm still running one kernel behind on manjaro. The latest is kernel is 5.7. Other issues reported by other people.

Comment: Having the same issue on my Lenovo ThinkPad T420, and your steps fixed the issue for me. Thank you. I have to wonder how many other things in this kernel (5.4.0-39) are not working properly, as I still get a "problem ... report to Ubuntu" pop-up box when I reboot. Not sure what the problem is, though.

Comment: Display issues  ( brighteness/nightlight, hybernate, fraction scaling, Nvidia settings not appering, etc. ) are often caused when Nvidia driver isn't truly compatible. I solved this basically with fresh new installation process with " install third party software" function. After that, system recognized automatically suitable graphics driver and now I am running on Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2) without any issues. It's also " Power safe" mode, not " Performance " . I didn't install additional drivers from " Software and Updates ". That wasn't working with my Omen laptop.